# Почему при использовании указателя не меняются данные Golang

Tags: golang

Работаю с указателями в GO. Если я правильно понял то указатели несут в себе участок памяти, в котором хранится значение. Значит при изменении этого участка памяти значение должно меняться везде (как я понимаю). Написал такой код:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type Animal struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

type Zoo struct {
    Animals []Animal
}

func (z *Zoo) FindAnimal(id int) (*Animal, error) {
    for _, animal := range z.Animals {
        if animal.ID == id {
            return &animal, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("Animal not found")
}

func main() {
    zoo := Zoo{
        Animals: []Animal{
            Animal{ID: 1, Name: "Monkey"},
            Animal{ID: 2, Name: "Tiger"},
            Animal{ID: 3, Name: "Wolf"},
        },
    }
    animal, err := zoo.FindAnimal(2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(animal) // &{2 Tiger}
    }
    animal.Name = "NewName"

    newAnimal, err := zoo.FindAnimal(2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(newAnimal) // &{2 Tiger}
    }
}
```

Я передаю указатель на экземпляр структуры `Animal` в функции `FindAnimal`. Я ожидаю что при изменении данных этого указателя данные будут так же меняться в экземпляре структуры `Zoo`, но этого почему то не происходит. Почему так? И что мне нужно поменять, чтобы это работало так, как я хочу

Answer (score 1):

Через 5 минут после публикации понял в чём проблема. Проблема в цикле, он когда достаёт значение из массива, то дублирует их, создавая новый участок памяти, соответственно меняться будет он, а не то что в массиве, решением стало изменить цикл так:

```
for i := 0; i < len(z.Animals); i++ {
    if z.Animals[i].ID == id {
        return &z.Animals[i], nil
    }
}
```